# How can check for an existing email in Laravel?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to check if the email is already exist my database on my **subscribes** table.

---

## Form

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/subscribe', 'class' => 'subscribe-form', 'role' =>'form')) !!}

<div class="form-group col-lg-7 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-offset-1">
  <label class="sr-only" for="mce-EMAIL">Email address</label>
  <input type="email" name="subscribe_email" class="form-control" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Enter email" required>

  <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
  <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_168a366a98d3248fbc35c0b67_73d49e0d23" value=""></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"></div>


{!! Form::close() !!}
```

---

## Controller

```
public function postSubscribe() {

    // Validation
    $validator = Validator::make( Input::only('subscribe_email'),

        array(
            'email'  =>'unique:subscribes',
            )
        );

    if ($validator->fails()) {

        return Redirect::to('/#footer')
        ->with('subscribe_error','This email is already subscribed to us.')
        ->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

    }else{

        dd("HERE");

        $subscribe        = new Subscribe;
        $subscribe->email = Input::get('subscribe_email');
        $subscribe->save();

        return Redirect::to('/thank-you');

    }

}
```

---

## Debuging Steps

I tried inputting email that I know already exist in my db.
I want to my validation to fail, and redirect me back to my `/#footer` (homepage).

I try printing `dd("HERE");` if my vaildation not fail.

BUT I keep getting `HERE` to print which mean my validation is not failing.
Why is that happening ? I'm completely blank out now.
Can someone please point out what I missed ?
I know I am very close.

Thanks.

Comment: try specifying the column name  `email` column of `subscribes` table
`$rules = array('email' => 'unique:subscribes,email');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your db field name is `email` not `subscribe_email`, your input param name however is. Laravel defaults to the fieldname given with the input, so in your case `subscribe_email`

Try this:

```
array(
    'subscribe_email'  => 'required|email|unique:subscribes,email',
)
```

This uses the db fieldname `email`, like you have, but the validation is on the field `subscribe_email`.

Comment: Work on the first try. Thank you so much. One thing, they don't need to be `required`, so I take them off.

Comment: Well if it's not required, you should add an additional check prior to your insert.The validation won't fail with an empty `subscribe_email` value, so you will end up with empty email values in your db. Besides that, if you have a unique index on your email db field, the second person submitting an empty value will trigger a db error (2 empty values != unique)

Comment: Is there a way to check or empty ? `length > 0` maybe ?

Comment: If you leave the email validation rule, you can just check if `Input::get('subscribe_email')` has a value, empty strings will validate, but if something is posted it checks if it's a valid email syntax. You can basically just do a `if (\Input::get('subscribe_email')) { // insert }`.

Answer (score 1):

try specifying the column name of email in subscribes table

```
$rules = array(
'email' => 'email|unique:subscribes,email'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the reason this is not working is because you are trying to match the `subscribe_email` field against validation for a `email` field, no match is being made. To fix you need to do this:

```
$validator = Validator::make( Input::only('subscribe_email'),
    array(
        'subscribe_email'  =>'email|unique:subscribes,email',
    )
);
```

Comment: You forgot this `email|`

Comment: @rangerover.js, there was nothing in your question that specified you needed/wanted that so I included only what was necessary to answer your question. I will update my answer to include it though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//put this in your controller
    if (User::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->exists()) {


        return back()->withErrors([

        'message' => 'Email is already taken'

        ]);

      //then go up and include


  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

Comment: This question was already answered. If your answer offers a better or alternative way to solve the problem, please explain it, don't just post code. Additionally, while I'm not familiar with the subject matter, it _looks_ like this answer doesn't actually answer the question.